# Getting bid recommendations for keywords without creating keywords

Tags: amazonsellercentral, amazon-advertising-api

I have been trying to get bid recommendations for a list of given keywords using this API => https://advertising.amazon.com/API/docs/en-us/sponsored-products/2-0/openapi#/Bid%20recommendations/createKeywordBidRecommendations

But it requires to provide an "adGroupId" beforehand for the same. Is there any way that we can get bid suggestions for a given list of keywords without providing the adgroup/campaign etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think Amazon tries to use historical performance as part of its bid recommendation. Either way, it does require it.

The best I can think of is to create a dummy adgroup and either delete it after or keep it around for this very purpose. It doesn't have to be enabled.